# HTML & CSS: Can't remove spacing between elemens

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time to remove the spaces between html elements.
I tried `display: inline-block`, `float: right`, ul view and many other ways.

As you can see in the snippet below, there is a white space between the images.

```css
#brandpage-banners .brandpage-banner-container {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="brandpage-banners">

    <div class="brandpage-banner-container">
      <img src="http://cdn.shoesonline.co.il/uploads/2016/12/columbia_brand_page_medium_banner_2.png">
    </div>

    <div class="brandpage-banner-container">
      <img src="http://cdn.shoesonline.co.il/uploads/2016/12/columbia_brand_page_medium_banner_1.png">
    </div>

</div>
```

So, how do I remove that space?

EDIT:
The border is actually a part of the image. Sorry guys, and thanks anyway, silly! :|

Comment: Open your browsers development console and find out what actually causes that gap.

Comment: Try to check your CSS class brandpage-banner-container, your have set it 50% as the width, try to lower it to 30% or simply remove the width boundary

Comment: `width` of your `divs` is the issue here..

Comment: Wtf, your images got a white border that is why is showing.

Comment: guys.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41240698/3924022

Comment: @Troyer if you view the result in full screen mode you will see the actual issue.. And I agree there is a white border on image..

Comment: op just accept an answer and move on >.>

Comment: Please properly investigate and then only ask a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the white border is a part of the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

And also the image border have some white space

```css
#brandpage-banners .brandpage-banner-container {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
#brandpage-banners .brandpage-banner-container img {
  width: 100%;
}
#brandpage-banners {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="brandpage-banners">

  <div class="brandpage-banner-container">
    <img src="http://cdn.shoesonline.co.il/uploads/2016/12/columbia_brand_page_medium_banner_2.png">
  </div>

  <div class="brandpage-banner-container">
    <img src="http://cdn.shoesonline.co.il/uploads/2016/12/columbia_brand_page_medium_banner_1.png">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
  #brandpage-banners .brandpage-banner-container {
    float: right;            
  }

 .brandpage-banner-container,.brandpage-banner-container img{
    position : relative;         
  }
```

```html
<div id="brandpage-banners">

    <div class="brandpage-banner-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRirSq4E2oGo5aoyRERdKnUYMkk3hxiApQ86NCLRB_i0hiuiDQF">
    </div>

    <div class="brandpage-banner-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRirSq4E2oGo5aoyRERdKnUYMkk3hxiApQ86NCLRB_i0hiuiDQF">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#brandpage-banners .brandpage-banner-container {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#brandpage-banners .brandpage-banner-container img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#brandpage-banners .brandpage-banner-container {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
```

If you make the width auto it will work.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried it is image border not elements. I just save as and open with Photoshop border is in all sides.